# Dryscrape (py): 'Operation on socket not supported'

Tags: python, web-scraping

Because of the huge hassles with finding a good scraping solution for Py, I'm using Dryscrape. I can't seem to get it to consistently work through a proxy, however. Some sites causes it to throw the following:

> InvalidResponseError: Error while loading URL
>   https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js: Operation on socket is not
>   supported (error code 99)

I guess it's some kind of proxy protection thingy, but I'm not breaking any TOS or anything. Only some sites do this, but the whole project is kind of relying on looking something up on the site daily. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I'm the author of the library and with the newest release I hope that most of the bugs of this kind should be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to tell without any code and knowing what you are trying to accomplish. But if you are trying to scrape a lot of pages at once, try throttling back the # of current connections to your proxy. Does it occur on the same page(s) each attempt?

Comment: Nope, was just trying to fetch one singleton page. But I actually randomly tried it again a few minutes later on the same page and it worked that time. So you think it is basically a problem with the proxy being overloaded or something? I was just testing it out with a random albanian proxy from a public list.

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly what my thinking was. If the problem isn't consistent across the same page, then its probably related to the proxy. And a random Albanian public proxy sounds like the issue rather than your code. ;-)

Comment: Just to clarify, the proxy I tested was capable of connecting to google.com, but not to siteofinterest.com - could this still be because of proxy QUALITY? Is it impossible for it to be caused by some kind of proxy protection? And why is it always googleplusone.js that triggers it?

Comment: I would recommend trying another proxy to see if you get the same result. I'm assuming it works fine with no proxy. Quality of the proxy service can matter, as it can fail on a number of operations resulting in an error and/or content filtering.